# My search didn't work

Tags: php, search, pdo

My search won't work and I don't know why. I would like to search for clients or tickets in my database. When I click on *search* while the *SEARCH* field ( input) is empty I get all clients BUT when I type some thing into the field I get nothing. Here is the code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="datatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="6%">name</th>
                <th width="6%">prenom</th>
                <th width="12%">adresse</th>
                <th width="3%">codepost</th>
                <th width="6%">ville</th>
                <th width="5%">telephone</th>
                <th width="8%">email</th>
                <th width="6%">type</th>
                <th width="5%">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            require 'database.php';

           $db = Database::connect();

            $statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE 'prenom' LIKE '%" . $_POST['prenom'] . "%' ORDER BY client_id DESC" );

          while($item = $statement->fetch())
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                // echo '<td>'. $item['id'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['name'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['prenom'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['adress'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['codepost'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['ville'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['telephone'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['email'] . '</td>';
                echo  '<td>'. $item['type'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td width=150>';
                echo '<a class="btn btn-default "  href="view.php?id='.$item['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>';
                echo ' ';
                echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="update.php?id='.$item['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>';
                echo ' ';
                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteclient.php?id='.$item['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            Database::disconnect();
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Never build SQL queries directly from user input!  From the look of your code you're using a DB abstraction layer that supports prepared statements, so use a prepared statement.  It will fix this issue, and will also protect you from SQL injection. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Sam Onela  thanks alot for the fast answer , to be honest am new to PDO and even PHP , i use to work on DELPHI :)

Comment: Sam Onela  thanks alot for the fast answer , to be honest am new to PDO and even PHP , i use to work on DELPHI :)  ,so i don't know how to do that prepare .

Comment: Sam Onela i been trying all night lol .. and i did it ,

Answer (score 0):

i finaly did it .. thanks to who helped me (
Sam Onela  ) here is the code if some one need ``it :=                               `
                
                
                    name
                    prenom
                    adresse
                    codepost
                    ville
                    telephone
                    email
                    type
                    Action
                
                
                
                prepare(" SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name LIKE ? ");
                    $req->execute(array('%' .$searchq. '%')) ;
                    $count = $req->rowCount();

```
                   echo " $count Résulta(s) trouvé pour <strong >$searchq></strong><hr/> " ;

                while($data = $req->fetch()) {

                   echo '<tr>';

                        echo  '<td>'. $data['name'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['prenom'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['adress'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['codepost'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['ville'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['telephone'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['email'] . '</td>';
                        echo  '<td>'. $data['type'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=150>';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-default "  href="view.php?id='.$data['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="update.php?id='.$data['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteclient.php?id='.$data['client_id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </a>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                            }



            }


            Database::disconnect();
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>`
```